# Subsrcibe a user in MailChimp API V3 give bad response

Tags: php, mailchimp

When I try to subscribe a user on mailchimp, it gives  an error response pasted below:

`‹<»nÃ0E…Ð’Å±2tòèt+ŠB‘[€.I¹0‚ü{i»è(Þ‹ÃC=Œ¬3šÁL"ó`mÀS‘úìbòSÌsïk¶¡ú–±ˆ“X‹ýÏìØb@¶HTé<¦Êìhµ¦3%mÜ·²¸\‘k#±R›áåréL@Q˜ß'ú+·[Ž"À×–”*pCØQNÇ=¼V‚{ÄÎ<£÷èá@qŒ¢¸Ó®Å'pDníuu,º¼øML_Gl†‡ÙQÇ4£1n•+~·H*±§?H¸«ÌT½;€ÛW|¹TÍóóùÿÿI*¯Q`

Here is the PHP code:

```
$apiKey = 'YOUR API KEY';
$listId = 'YOUR LIST ID';
$url2 = 'https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'.$listId.'/members/';

$args = array(
        'email' => 'abc@xyz.com',
        'status' => 'subscribed',
        'merge_fields' => array(
            'first_name' => 'WOW',
            'last_name' => 'WOW',
            'mobile'=>'',
            'message'=>'',
            'ID'=>'000'
        ));

function syncMailchimp($url,$apiKey,$args) {

    $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user apikey:" . $apiKey);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/3.0');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($args));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
}
```

Is the server sending bad data or is client side using a wrong encoding and how do I fix it?

Comment: Something bad happened to yours post encoding.

Comment: Can you please tell me where ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the key called `email` to `email_address` appears to have fixed it.  Perhaps that bad key caused the server to puke.

```
 $args = array(
        'email' => 'abc@xyz.com',
        'status' => 'subscribed',
        'merge_fields' => array(
            'first_name' => 'WOW',
            'last_name' => 'WOW',
            'mobile'=>'',
            'message'=>'',
            'ID'=>'000'
        ));
```

to

```
$args = array(
        'email_address' => 'abc@xyz.com',
        'status' => 'subscribed',
        'merge_fields' => array(
            'first_name' => 'WOW',
            'last_name' => 'WOW',
            'mobile'=>'',
            'message'=>'',
            'ID'=>'000'
        ));
```